# SQL count columns and create table with computation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure how to word the title correctly, so I apologize if it's confusing.

What I need to do is to count how many projects are run by each department, I need to display each department name and assign a name to the colum with computed results

[DEPARTMENT Table Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL1RE.png)

[PROJECT Table Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq8qz.png)

This is what I have tried so far, but it returns an error:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentName, COUNT(*) AS AmountOfProjects
    FROM DEPARTMENT, PROJECT;
```

Comment: "it returns an error" - what is the error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried user3083310 solution something still looked wrong, all the Departments were showing 5 projects, and that is wrong. I added the following join and it worked:

```
    SELECT DEPARTMENT.DepartmentName, Count(*) AS AmountOfProjects
    FROM PROJECT, DEPARTMENT
    WHERE PROJECT.Department = DEPARTMENT.DepartmentName
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.DepartmentName;
```

And the output is the following that matches the information the project table.

**Department Name**: Account Finance Marketing

**AmountOfProjects**: 1 - 2 - 2

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DepartmentName, Count(1) AS AmountOfProjects
FROM Project
GROUP BY DepartmentName
```

You don't need the Department table since the Full Name of the Department is in the projects table.

You left out the Group By.  Whenever you have an aggregate function in your select, you need a Group By

Comment: Whenever you have an aggregate and non-aggregate fields in your select, you need a `GROUP BY`